# how to remove duplicate row based on a column value

Tags: excel, vba

I have below sheet where column B has server names repeated two times, some time many times or not repeated at all. Corresponding column C has size which could be same or less or different number or all have same number. I want to delete all dups row leaving behind one row which has bigger number in Column C or same ( If all has same number). I tried to loop thru with below code

```
Option Explicit
Sub removeDups()
Dim NumberOfValues, counter As Integer
Dim name, foundname As String
Dim value1 As Long
Dim i As Long

NumberOfValues = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To NumberOfValues
            
            name = Range("B" & i).Value
            value1 = Range("C" & i).Value
            foundname = True
            counter = 1
            If counter > 1 Then
                 'don't know how to loop'
            End If
     

Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You don't say what the problem is, so I'm going to guess some rows aren't getting deleted. To solve this problem, you want to loop backwards: `For i = NumberOfValues to 1 step -1`

Comment: counter = 1, is assigned before, If counter > 1 Then, so the conditional is not entered. Also, I'm assuming the data is sorted by column B, and Column C descending, it would make things a little easier if it is. One more thing, foundname = True, declare foundname as boolean

Comment: Hi i am not able to get logic how should i loop so loop checks name and size once new name comes , stop and get size which is largest one. Then delete all row except row which had largest number or pick one randomly if all have same size.

Comment: So if there are two rows with the exact same values, you want to keep them?

Comment: If two rows has same value then i want delete one. i have not pasted entire sheet here which has 2000 rows. some times there more than 2 , 3 or more rows for same name. so if they all have same value then delete all leaving behind just one row. This is just tricky , don't know how to think. is there better method ??

Comment: Can you not just use the remove duplicates functionality built into Excel?  No need for VBA that way.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2  Select columns A and B and then hit remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the data then scan up the sheet and delete the row if the one above is a duplicate.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub removeDups()
    
    Dim rng As Range, lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .UsedRange
        
        ' Sort B asc C desc
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                 Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                 Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        
        'scan up
        For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            ' check if record above is same
            If .Cells(i - 1, "B") = .Cells(i, "B") Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
                '.Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
        
    End With
    MsgBox n & " duplicates deleted", vbInformation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need VBA for this.  You can just use the standard Remove Duplicates functionality.

[image: Before]

Sort your data first to ensure the **Value 1** column is sorted descending.

[image: Sort]

Now remove the duplicates being careful to only compare the first two columns ...

[image: Remove Duplicates]

The end result should be what you need ...

[image: After]

Comment: above suggestion still has duplicate.

Comment: @postmaster420, it's not possible.  If there's a duplicate then there's a single character or something that you can't see, like a space.  That's standard Excel functionality and will work for true duplicates.

Comment: Quite honestly that's what I do.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this in different ways:

**Excel 365:**

You may benefit fron UNIQUE and MAXIFS:

[image]

Formula in E3 is

```
 =UNIQUE(A1:B26)
```

and formula in G3 is

```
 =MAXIFS($C$1:$C$26;$B$1:$B$26;F3;$A$1:$A$26;E3)
```

Then copy/paste as values and delete original data

**Any Excel Version:**

You can use Pivot Tables to get the range you want and copy/paste. Just create Pivot Table, Columns A and B into rows section and Column C into Values section and Choose MAX instead of SUM

[image]

**VBA**

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long
Dim IR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim MyDict As Object
Dim MyKey As Variant
Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
IR = 2 'initial row of data

For i = IR To LR Step 1
    If Not MyDict.Exists(Range("B" & i).Value) Then
        MyDict.Add Range("B" & i).Value, Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(MAX((B" & IR & ":B" & LR & "=""" & Range("B" & i).Value & """)*C" & IR & ":C" & LR & "))")
    End If
Next i

'destiny of new data
'as example, we start pasting data in row 2 column E
i = IR
For Each MyKey In MyDict
    Range("E" & i).Value = MyKey
    Range("F" & i).Value = MyDict(MyKey)
    i = i + 1
Next MyKey

MyDict.RemoveAll
Set MyDict = Nothing

'rest of code to delete data or whatever


End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Duplicates With Lesser Value

- Loops through the column of the keys (`B`) and if they are not already in the dictionary, adds them, as the keys, and the reference to the associated value cells (`C`), as the items, to it.
- If they are already added, then it checks the current value (`C`) against the previous value of the item (which is a one-cell range).
- Whichever is greater, remains, or gets set as the dictionary item, while the other one is combined into the delete range.
- Finally, the delete range's entire rows are deleted in one go.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDupesLess()
    
    Const fRow As Long = 1
    Const uCol As String = "B"
    Const vCol As String = "C"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, uCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim urg As Range: Set urg = ws.Cells(fRow, uCol).Resize(lRow - fRow + 1)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim drg As Range, uCell As Range, vCell As Range
    Dim uKey As Variant, vKey As Variant
    
    For Each uCell In urg.Cells
        uKey = uCell.Value
        Set vCell = uCell.EntireRow.Columns(vCol)
        vKey = vCell.Value
        If Not IsError(uKey) Then
            If Len(uKey) > 0 Then
                If IsNumeric(vKey) Then
                    If dict.Exists(uKey) Then ' unique name exists
                        If dict(uKey).Value < vKey Then ' the value is greater
                            Set drg = RefCombinedRange(drg, dict(uKey))
                            Set dict(uKey) = vCell
                        Else ' the value is less than
                            Set drg = RefCombinedRange(drg, vCell)
                        End If
                    Else ' new unique name
                        Set dict(uKey) = vCell
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next uCell
                        
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        drg.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    MsgBox "Removed duplicates.", vbInformation

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a range combined from two ranges.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCombinedRange( _
    ByVal CombinedRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If CombinedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set RefCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set RefCombinedRange = Union(CombinedRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @postmaster420, you need to go back over all of your previously asked questions and flag the answer you accepted as the answer.  Have a look at other questions with answers and notice the green tick, that's what I'm talking about.  It helps others and rewards those who help.

Comment: i am hard understnding accept green flag, where is this flag ?